# Detect Circles in Raspberry pi with PiCamera

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, object-detection, hough-transform

I want the Raspberry pi B+ to detect circles in images. I've been looking for some code, and I tried to use them with the raspberry pi. Here is my conclusion code, but the mainly problem is that it doesn't get the image with the detected objects (I am using as an example a tennis ball), it just get the image without the draw circle and rectangle.

```
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import time
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
os.system('sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2')

h=200
w=300
camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (w, h)
camera.framerate = 24
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(w, h))
time.sleep(0.1)

for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):

image_RGB = frame.array
copy_RGB = image_RGB.copy() 
grey = cv2.cvtColor(image_RGB, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

img_circles = None
img_circles = cv2.HoughCircles(grey, cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1.2, 100)



if img_circles is not None:
    img_circles = np.round(img_circles[0, :]).astype("int")
    for (x, y, r) in img_circles:

        cv2.circle(copy_RGB, (x, y), r, (0, 255, 0), 4)
        cv2.rectangle(copy_RGB, (x - 5, y - 5),(x + 5, y + 5), (0, 128, 255, -1))

cv2.imshow("Copy with Detected Object", copy_RGB)

key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
rawCapture.truncate(0)
if key == ord("q"):
    break
```

Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you really want a `dp = 1.2` and a `minDist = 100` in the hough function call or do you want `cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 2, 100)` ? Have you checked if any circle is found at all? Maybe that is the problem...

Comment: Can you share your images?

Comment: If this is solved, please answer your own question (or delete this question) and ask a new question.